# Installing an older version of Storybook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

I am having an issue with Storybook 6.3 since it uses Webpack 5 and I am installing it on a clean create-react-app which uses Webpack 4.41.8.

I tried to update react webpack and all and still no luck. The problem started after I tried to add sass support for my storybook project, and went into dependency hell.

I just want to install an older version of Storybook like 5.3, how do I do that? Since Storybook uses `npx sb init`?

Comment: Try  `npx sb@5.3 init`.

Comment: i did, it installed 6.3.6

Answer (score 0):

You could downgrade storybook.
[This is the official manual](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/upgrading#prereleases)

> If you'd like to downgrade to a stable version, manually edit the
> package version numbers in your package.json and re-install.

Answer (score -1):

So in the end I found [this](https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324) to be the answer to all my problems (having latest Storybook and working sass support) that has been using the standard webpack-loaders as shown in the [official Storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#gatsby-focus-wrapper), do not forget to import them and the entry .scss file in the *root/.storybook/preview.js* file e.g. *import "!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../stories/assets/main.scss"*

Comment: does not answer how to downgrade storybook

Comment: This does not help in downgrading storybook.